# Kafka: Describe Consumer Group Offset

Tags: apache-kafka

While the Kafka consumer application is up and running, we are able to use the kafka-consumer-groups.sh to describe and retrieve the offset status.

However, if the application goes down, then the command just displays the application is in REBALANCING.

Is there a way to just see the lag of a particular consumer group, even if the application is not up and running?

For example, I would like this output

```
GROUP|TOPIC|PARTITION|CURRENT-OFFSET|LOG-END-OFFSET|LAG
hrly_ingest_grp|src_hrly|4|63832846|63832846|0
hrly_ingest_grp|src_hrly|2|38372346|38372346|0
hrly_ingest_grp|src_hrly|0|58642250|58642250|0
hrly_ingest_grp|src_hrly|5|96295762|96295762|0
hrly_ingest_grp|src_hrly|3|50602337|50602337|0
hrly_ingest_grp|src_hrly|1|29288993|29288993|0
```

Comment: Can you post the command ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use kt (Kafka tool) - https://github.com/fgeller/kt

Command to query offset and lag will be as follow:

```
kt group -group groupName -topic topicName -partitions all
```

Answer (score 0):

Even the consumer application is down, this command will show the offset of each consumer of that group

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group
```

Output:

```
TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                    HOST            CLIENT-ID
topic3          0          241019          395308          154289          consumer2-e76ea8c3-5d30-4299-9005-47eb41f3d3c4 /127.0.0.1      consumer2
topic2          1          520678          803288          282610          consumer2-e76ea8c3-5d30-4299-9005-47eb41f3d3c4 /127.0.0.1      consumer2
topic3          1          241018          398817          157799          consumer2-e76ea8c3-5d30-4299-9005-47eb41f3d3c4 /127.0.0.1      consumer2
topic1          0          854144          855809          1665            consumer1-3fc8d6f1-581a-4472-bdf3-3515b4aee8c1 /127.0.0.1      consumer1
topic2          0          460537          803290          342753          consumer1-3fc8d6f1-581a-4472-bdf3-3515b4aee8c1 /127.0.0.1      consumer1
topic3          2          243655          398812          155157          consumer4-117fe4d3-c6c1-4178-8ee9-eb4a3954bee0 /127.0.0.1      consumer4
```

Comment: According to this, it isn't down...?

Comment: But this command is used to get offset right? It don't have anything to do with application right? @cricket_007

Comment: The question says the command works fine (as you've shown), but the real problem is *if the application goes down, then the command just displays the application is in REBALANCING*

Comment: Do that really happens @cricket_007  i tested it when application is down but it works for me, have you tried ?

Comment: I know it says either "group is rebalancing" or "no active members", but it still shows the offsets for me. Just there are `-` marks for the last three columns